# mimic-iii question about ICD9

Tags: mimic-iii

I have access to mimic database now, and for my research I need every patient's symptoms like fever, bleeding , .... I would like to know if this information is provided in the database and which table has this information?

In addition, I want to get query from the database to find all the disease that every patient has, So can you please help me if there is any code that I can use?

Also, in "PATIENTS.csv" file, I can see a column with DOB name and I supposed that it has the date of birth of every patient, but my problem is that those are like for future for example one of them is 3/13/2075 ! so could you please also help me to find patient's date of birth?

Answer (score 1):

For the last question: you can see http://mimic.physionet.org/mimicdata/time/ "All dates in the database have been shifted to protect patient confidentiality." I believe you can still calculate patient's age at admission

For the other questions, I hope someone else can help as I have not used MIMIC for half a year now...

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with MIMIC quite intensively and there is no data on symptoms in the structured way listed.

However, you can extract these from Notes Events table (history & physical note, H&P note, admission note, transfer note etc...  would be history of present illness and review of systems sections) using natural language processing.

I think this may be interesting, but it would require some work.

Comment: There are ICD9 codes for symptoms (http://www.icd9data.com/2015/Volume1/780-799/780-789/default.htm). A lead, perhaps?